# Replacing existing drwable in imageview is wrong scaled on some devices

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, scale

**The Situation:**

I have a imageview with a layer list of two drwables. 
The frame drwable is 800x400px and the cover drawable is 800x380px.
Both images reside in the folder drawable

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/preview_img_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/result_preview"/>
```

The Drwable layer list in drawable/result_preview

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/cover">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:src="@drawable/cover" />
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/frame">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:src="@drawable/frame" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This setup works as expected the cover is displayed framed on all devices. Now the user can replace the sample cover with another cover of the same size.

Replacing the cover in the layer list and leave the frame as is.

```
LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.result_preview);

InputStream coverIs = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(coverUri));
this.drwCover = (BitmapDrawable) BitmapDrawable.createFromStream(coverIs, coverUri);
drwCover.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
//drwCover.getBitmap().setDensity(160);
layer.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.cover, drwCover);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(layer);
```

**The Problem:**

Replacing the current cover with a new one (same dimensions as old) produces different results depending on the Device used.

On a device with a 3.2 screen and a 480x320 resolution the cover replaced fits in the frame. On a device with a 3.7 and a 800x480 resolution the replaced cover is displayed smaller then the old one.

What I found out is that the drwable in the imageview on the small device has a intrinsic height of 800x400 same as the dimensions of the drawable. 
On the bigger screen the intrinsic height of the drawable is 30% bigger.

I know the the intrinsic values may differ from screen to screen.

What I was expecting is that the drawable that replaces the old one should will be scaled up the same way the old one was to +30%. But this did not happen.

**Question:**

Is there a option to tell the imageview or the layer list to Adpt itself? I think there should be a way to do so because the system did it already at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other having the same problem. 9patch png is a solution to a problem I don't have.

So far the only thing that came close to solve the problem was to put my resources into the folder drawable-nodpi.  [Here is the reference to the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd suggest doing the cover/frame differently:

1. make your frame a [nine-patch drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html), so you can define in the nine-patch the padding that will remain visible when the cover is drawn on top of it.
2. put the frame drawable as a `background`
3. set the cover as the `src` of the image, and not the layer list
4. don't forget to set a `scaleType` for your `ImageView`, play with the different options, so suit your needs.

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/preview_img_view"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_weight="0.9"
>     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
>     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
>     android:background="@drawable/frame"
>     android:src="@drawable/cover"/>
> ```

Comment: Thx for the tip I looked at your recommendation. In my example I use 2 layers but in reality I have more. Also I am using images and can not stretch them only scale.

Comment: you can choose how to scale the images in the scaleType, some of the possible values of it stretch the image, and some scale it.